# How to avoid escape characters added to a variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, escaping, html-escape-characters

Hello I have the following variable:

`var delete_query = []`

Then I assign

`delete_query[0] = "CALL apoc.index.relationships('TO','statement:241') YIELD rel WITH DISTINCT rel DELETE rel;"`

However, when I then print it out `console.log(delete_query);`

I see something like

`[ 'CALL apoc.index.relationships(\'TO\',\'statement:ae976060-1649-11e8-b256-ff710bab2aaf\') YIELD rel WITH DISTINCT rel DELETE rel;']`

How do I avoid escape character `\` being added?

Thanks!

Comment: What browser does this?

Comment: @epascarello Node.Js

Answer (score 1):

No character has been added to the string. This is just the console adding it for display, so that it is unambiguous with respect to the quoting. It's essentially showing you the string as it would have to be written in source code, if it were written in source code.

Comment: Although my browser does not do this.